# Change links text size in TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using TTTAttributedLabel for showing link in labels.
Now i want to change font size for only links. Any guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TTTAttributedLabel` has a property `linkAttributes`, which it will apply to every link:

```
TTTAttributedLabel *someLabel;

NSMutableDictionary *baseAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
UIFont *baseFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
CTFontRef baseFontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)baseFont.fontName, baseFont.pointSize, NULL);

baseAttributes[(__bridge NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName] = (__bridge id)baseFontRef;
CFRelease(baseFontRef);

someLabel.linkAttributes = baseAttributes;
```

Comment: just a question can we make a image wrap text with TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but there is not an easy way to insert an image into an attributed label (unless you want an Emoji icon).  If you're making a more complex flow layout, I'd suggest using `UIWebView`.